# Ignorar pontuação em uma sequência de números usando Regex com Java

Tags: java, regex

Eu tenho o seguinte input:

```
Fatura Cliente:  1.7852964.34 
CPF/CNPJ:  09022317000222
```

Eu preciso pegar apenas os números da "Fatura Cliente", ignorando pontuações, retornando apenas `1785296434`, pra isso eu to usando o seguinte regex:

```
Fatura Cliente[\D]+(\S+)
```

Porém posteriormente preciso tratar e dar um replace nas pontuações pra transformar em uma sequencia de números.

Como faço para que o regex já me retorne uma sequencia de números ignorando pontuações pelo capture group sem precisar dar o replace posteriormente no código?

Capturar pelo primeiro regex já formatada sem as pontuações é possível ou preciso dar um String.replace ou String.replaceAll(regex) após a primeira captura com regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Regex

O Regex: `\b(\d+)(\.|,|\b)`

## Resultado

Com estas strings de teste:

```
Fatura Cliente: 6.823935.10
Fatura Cliente: 6,823935,10
Fatura, Cliente: 6,823935.10
Fatura. Cl1ente: 6.823935,10
```

E o replace com: `$1` , em que $1 significa o primeiro grupo de captura.

Os seguintes resultados são obtidos:

```
Fatura Cliente: 682393510
Fatura Cliente: 682393510
Fatura, Cliente: 682393510
Fatura. Cl1ente: 682393510
```

Testar demo no [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgIDgjLSYCQw/index.html) ou [FreeFormatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

## Explicação `\b(\d+)(\.|,|\b)`

- `\b` - A posição de um limite de palavra, ou seja, a letra não pode ser seguida de outra letra.
- Primeiro Grupo de Captura `(\d+)`

  - `\d` - Corresponde ao dígito igual a [0-9]
  - `+` - Quantificador que corresponde de uma a ilimitadas vezes, quantas vezes for possível (greedy)
- Segundo Grupo de Captura `(\.|,| |$)`

  - `|` - Ou
  - `\.` - Corresponde literalmente ao ponto final
  - `,` - Corresponde literalmente à vírgula
  - `\b` - A posição de um limite de palavra, ou seja, a letra não pode ser seguida de outra letra.

### EDIT:

Você não precisaria de Regex, já que é uma SubString capturada, somente substituir os pontos e vírgulas com replace resolveria seu problema.

Não é possível fazer somente com Regex. Você precisaria de um passo a mais para tratar isso, seja com replace ou com outro método. Há alguns modos na resposta do [@Douglas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292550/ignorar-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-uma-sequ%C3%AAncia-de-n%C3%BAmeros-usando-regex-com-java/292580#292558).

Comment: Ela é uma substring captura de uma string usando regex, e nesse regex de captura dessa substring já queria que viesse a sequencia de números formatados, sem pontos e virgulas. Eu capturo a substring usando o regex "Fatura Cliente[\D]+(?<clientNumber>\S+" e matcher.group("clientNumber") é "6.823935.10", porém eu preciso que já venha formado sem pontos e virgulas: "682393510", compreende?

Comment: Já tentou usar o replace em cada SubMatch? Não possuo experiência em java, mas seria algo do tipo: `String TirarPonto = SubMatchDoRegex.replace(".", "");`

Comment: A principio eu queria que o capture group matcher.group("clientNumber") já retornasse com ela formatada pelo próprio regex. E sim, é dessa forma que estou usando atualmente, me serve por enquanto, porém a dúvida é mais curiosa do que necessidade, e também pra deixar o código mais limpo futuramente, pois uso muito regex.

Comment: Você precisaria de um passo a mais para tratar isso. Não é possível fazer somente com Regex.

Comment: Perfeito. Basicamente o que eu precisava saber era que não é possível, pois assim a única saída então é formatar com um String.replace ou string.replaceAll(regex) após capturar a string com a numeração + pontuação. Vou editar a pergunta inicial, dai então você pode editar a sua resposta e informar que não é possível capturar ela formatada diretamente. Dessa forma posso marcar como aceita pra ajudar futuros usuários q venham ter a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Implementação em Java

```
public static void main(String[] argvs) {
    // Com ponto
    String numeroSemPonto = extraiNumeracao("Fatura Cliente: 6.823935.10");
    System.out.println(numeroSemPonto);

    // Com vírgula
    String numeroSemVirgula = extraiNumeracao("Fatura Cliente: 6,823935,10");
    System.out.println(numeroSemVirgula);

    //** Outra opção **//

    // Com ponto
    String numeroSemPonto2 = extraiNumeracao2("Fatura Cliente: 6.823935.10");
    System.out.println(numeroSemPonto2);

    // Com vírgula
    String numeroSemVirgula2 = extraiNumeracao2("Fatura Cliente: 6,823935,10");
    System.out.println(numeroSemVirgula2);
}

public static String extraiNumeracao(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    String resultado = "";

    while (m.find()) {
        resultado += m.group();
    }

    return resultado;
}

// Outra opção
public static String extraiNumeracao2(String str) {
    return str.split(": ")[1].replace(",", "").replace(".", "");
}
```

Comment: Estou utilizando Java. O regex "\\d+" retorna apenas os números antes do primeiro ".", quer seria o "6" nesse caso. Editei com mais informações.

Comment: Coloquei dois métodos, um usando Regex e outro usando 'replace' como sugerido por @danieltakeshi